# I have a text file encoded in several different formats, I need to force that file text to be UTF-8 on Javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, encode

I have a web application where I need to read from the hard disk a text file, the problem is that I don't know in which format is saved.  Could be in the 4 formats that window's notepad let you save the txt file like ANSI, UNICODE, UNICODE Big ENDIAN and UTF-8.

My web application already reads UTF-8, but if for example the user saves the file on ANSI, my web app will display some weird characteres.

I'm using this function in JAVASCRIPT to read the file text from the hard drive

```
 $.get('./file.txt', function (data) {
        document.getElementById('file').value = data;
 }, 'text');
```

Is there any way to get this fixed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you just want to change the format of the file, use notepad++ to save the files. It allowsyou to change the codification.

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify the user's file, I am just able to read it....

Comment: What is `$` and `$.get()`? Which library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
var newString = decodeURIComponent(escape(oldstring));
```

The escape function will encode the characters as two-digit or four digit hex strings, while the encodeURIComponent function will encode them as UTF-8.